# Rodeo 2.5 change terminal color theme

Tags: ide, themes, rodeo

I was looking for a decent IDE for data science, and Rodeo seems about right.

I want to change the theme color to dark, but in Preferences -> Editor -> Theme only changes a part of the theme, But not the terminal and the other stuff.

[image]

Is it possible to change the color of the terminal and the rest? Because It's not in the preferences.